# How to get a list of all predicates in an RDF file or ontology using SPARQL code?

Tags: sparql, rdf

I want to know how to download/ extract a list of predicates from RDF/ ontology file using SPARQL?

For example, say we are talking about the "rdfs" URI. I want to get all properties (predicates) such as range, domain, type etc. to be listed. Is this possible? Or am I making a conceptual mistake here?

Comment: so you tried basically nothing so far? No SPARQL tutorial read? Not even used the search function? It's also not 100% clear what you're asking for, all predicates of an ontology or all built-in predicates of the RDF, RDFS and OWL vocabulary. For the latter, the corresponding ontologies have to be loaded explicitly in addition to the ontology of your domain of interest.

Comment: And the absic query itself is trivial, it contains a simple triple pattern `?s ?p ?o` in case those predicates are all used by instance data. If not, schema triples have to be queries as well, like `?p rdfs:range ?r`, `?p a rdf:Property`, `?p1 rdfs:subPropertyOf ?p2` and so  on and so forth - so, with schema triples the query becomes much more complex depending on your schema resp. the language, i.e. just RDFS triples or also OWL axioms

Comment: For just the RDFS predicates, load the RDFS ontology and query for `?p a rdf:Property`

Comment: Thank you! Sorry if the question was unclear. I just posted a more clear one. To answer your questions, I have read about SPARQL and wrote some trivial codes about 6 years ago. But even at the time, I had some problems with some concepts. For example, what to do when coming across a new ontology and how to know its predicates in order to be able to use it. Here, I mentioned RDFS to make it easier. Actually, right now I am querying an ontology in neuroscience called NIFSTD. I don't know how to find its predicate list such as 'overlap', 'volume', etc.

Comment: ok. well as I said, it depends on the data resp. ontology. Ideally, there are triples that declare the type of each property. In that case, you will find all predicates by doing `SELECT ?p {VALUES ?type {rdf:Property owl:ObjectProperty owl:DatatypeProperty} ?p a ?type}` - try it out, maybe this already works?

Comment: `select distinct ?p {?s ?p ?o}`?

Comment: Funny that I have tried this before, but it came back with no results. I checked it on SPARQL Playground and it worked! Is it possible that since the file is stored as 'turtle' format these are not working? However, I used Python's rdflib and parsed it as turtle and got some results.

Comment: @AKSW the 'SELECT ?p {VALUES ?type {rdf:Property owl:ObjectProperty owl:DatatypeProperty} ?p a ?type}' comes back with a list of mostly relations (predicates) defined by another ontology (OBO). However, I am interested in querying the NIF ontology. So, I added a 'nif' to the values, but it had no effect!

Comment: @RFNO my query just returns all properties that are **explicitly** declared to be a property. If those triples are missing, indeed the properties wouldn't be returned. Can you explain which properties for example are missing? the other option to get used properties is to do `select distinct ?p where {?s ?p ?o}` - indeed, you could combine both queries via `UNION`operator

Comment: I thought the 'values' keyword can show the specific results I am looking for. I wanted to just list all properties related to the NIF ontology. That's why I used 'nif' with the 'values' keyword in the code you mentioned above.

Comment: What about this: `SELECT DISTINCT ?p WHERE {?s ?p ?o .  FILTER (REGEX(STR(?p), "nif", "i")). }
order by ?p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DISTINCT` operator along with a SPARQL query that lists all the statements from a graph. You can also use `ORDER BY` to make long lists easier to browse.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o
}
ORDER BY ?p
```

---

If the graph you're querying against is an ontology, you might want to select all entities that have the `rdf:Property` type rather than the predicates in the graph.

When performing this request, make sure inference is enabled since most predicates are typed `owl:ObjectProperty` or `owl:DatatypeProperty`, which are subclasses of `rdf:Property`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?property WHERE {
    ?property a rdf:Property
}
ORDER BY ?property
```

Comment: The question is not about getting all `rdf:Property` in a graph, but I can mention it.

Comment: the question is *"I want to get all properties (predicates)*" - if the ontology is just a schema – and that's what I already mentioned in my comments below the question – just getting predicates of triples doesn't do anything. Moreover, if it is an OWL ontology, even your second query doesn't work. Just to show you that I'm not telling stupdi things, here is the ontology that the TO tries to work with: `http://purl.org/nif/ontology/nif.owl` - not that using `rdflib` is the wrong API for this kind of ontologies anyways, but that's what I already told him in his other question

Comment: Why wouldn't the second query work on OWL ontologies? As I stated in my answer, `owl:ObjectProperty` and `owl:DatatypeProperty` are subclasses of `rdf:Property`, so if the query is performed with inference, they will be returned.